# Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleDebug] ERROR - Android Studio 3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.3

i am new of android studio. and i am making my first apps, in the previous version 2.3 i dont have problem or stuck when making apps. but when i upgrade to the new version 3.0 i got problem, and when i trying to rebuild apk. it stuck at `Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleDebug]` . same problem when i build apk, rebuild and clean up.

anyone can help fix this ?

I still cant fix this.

```
10 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 1 up-to-date

Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleDebug]

    Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
    :clean
    :app:clean
    :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :app:preDebugBuild
    :app:compileDebugAidl
    :app:compileDebugRenderscript
    :app:checkDebugManifest
    :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
    :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
    :app:generateDebugResValues
    :app:generateDebugResources
    :app:mergeDebugResources
    Exception in thread "queued-resource-processor_4" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\kreuzell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt2.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReadyOrFail(AaptProcess.java:196)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptQueueThreadContext.creation(AaptQueueThreadContext.java:56)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:213)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Exception in thread "queued-resource-processor_2" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\kreuzell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt2.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReadyOrFail(AaptProcess.java:196)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptQueueThreadContext.creation(AaptQueueThreadContext.java:56)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:213)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Exception in thread "queued-resource-processor_1" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\kreuzell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt2.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReadyOrFail(AaptProcess.java:196)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptQueueThreadContext.creation(AaptQueueThreadContext.java:56)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:213)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Exception in thread "queued-resource-processor_3" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\kreuzell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt2.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReadyOrFail(AaptProcess.java:196)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptQueueThreadContext.creation(AaptQueueThreadContext.java:56)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:213)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Android Studio 3.0 users with similar build errors.

Your Error logs say:

```
Exception in thread "queued-resource-processor_4" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\kreuzell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt2.exe can run successfully **(some anti-virus may block it)** or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
```

It means, if your Internet connection is fine, your **aapt process** may be blocked by your antivirus or firewall. Try disabling your **antivirus** and build again.

If not works, you can try disabling AAPT2 like this:

> Improved incremental resource processing using AAPT2, which is enabled by default. If you are experiencing issues while using AAPT2, you can disable it by setting **android.enableAapt2=false** in your **gradle.properties** file and restarting the Gradle daemon by running ./gradlew --stop from the command line.

Comment: Thank You. Its work now. I disable mu antivirus then restart.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in system variables:

```
SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT = 30
```

Then restart Windows, works beautifully for me.