# Exception in thread "queued-resource-processor_4

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-3.0

suddenly i had an issue with android studio before week ago it works proper but now when i run the app it generate "Queued-resource-processor-4" Exception
I already tried answer that is

1. **Try Disabling Antivirus** - I am Not Using Antivirus
2. **Adding Environment variable**  - No Success
3. **android.enableAapt2=false(in gradle.properties)** - not working and also display warning that this is deprecated
   Here is the log
4. **Downgrade The Gradle Plugin** - Still No Success

Here is the log

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources]

Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE

Exception in thread "queued-resource-processor_4" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\kreuzell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt2.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReadyOrFail(AaptProcess.java:196)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptQueueThreadContext.creation(AaptQueueThreadContext.java:56)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:213)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "queued-resource-processor_2" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\kreuzell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt2.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReadyOrFail(AaptProcess.java:196)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptQueueThreadContext.creation(AaptQueueThreadContext.java:56)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:213)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "queued-resource-processor_1" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at C:\Users\kreuzell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt2.exe can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReadyOrFail(AaptProcess.java:196)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptQueueThreadContext.creation(AaptQueueThreadContext.java:56)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:213)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Before error it opens multiple aapt.exe console window shown in below picture
[image]

**Update :**

**build.gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '28.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.blackhat.something"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}


dependencies {
 compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.reginald:patternlock:1.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'
compile 'com.devs:acr:1.0.1'
}
```

Someone Please Help Me With This........

Comment: Please check the following link :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47119220/2919483

Comment: I told you not working....I tried every answer that is related to this question

Comment: Can you go to a terminal and try executing "C:\Users\kreuzell\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt2.exe compile -h"?

Comment: yes i can execute aapt2.exe compile -h but it displays unknown flag -h

Comment: Can you try upgrading the build tools version?

Comment: I try upgrading build tools but no success

Comment: add more discription about your build.gradle file

Comment: which virsion you used currently

Comment: question updated..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this problem was caused by an virus blocking my Aapt.exe file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved it by updating gradle and in your case it's not working because you have to change the distribution path of gradle as well. Try this:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha17'
```

and in gradle.properties add this:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.8-all.zip
```

Hope this works....